# Adding textBoxes (two or more) on same word page on specific location (x,y) using spire.doc

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, spire.doc

I am trying to create word document with few text boxes (more will be added later) on specific location (x and y) on same page using Spire.doc. But this code is generating two pages. Any help with this?

If the a any other way it is not necessary to use Spire.
Please keep in minde thet i am novice to programing, thanks.

```
  string TEMPprocitano; 
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        citanjeReda();
    }
    public void citanjeReda()
    {
      if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
              {
         int brojRedova=File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Count();
         StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                  for (int i = 0; i <= brojRedova; i++)
                  {
                      TEMPprocitano = sr.ReadLine();
                      f1(); f3(); 
                  }
                  sr.Close();
              }
    }
    public void f1()  //doc_pers_no 11
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder F1 = new StringBuilder(TEMPprocitano);
            F1.Remove(0, 22);
            F1.Remove(11, 698);
            MessageBox.Show(F1.ToString());

            //Create a Word document
            Document doc = new Document();
            Section section = doc.AddSection();
            Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();

            //Append a Textbox to paragraph
            Spire.Doc.Fields.TextBox tb = paragraph.AppendTextBox(170, 20);

            //Set the position of Textbox
            tb.Format.HorizontalOrigin = HorizontalOrigin.Page;
            tb.Format.HorizontalPosition = 150;
            tb.Format.VerticalOrigin = VerticalOrigin.Page;
            tb.Format.VerticalPosition = 50;

            CharacterFormat format = new CharacterFormat(doc);
            format.FontName = "Calibri";
            format.FontSize = 11;
            format.Bold = false;



            Paragraph par1 = tb.Body.AddParagraph();
            par1.AppendText(F1.ToString()).ApplyCharacterFormat(format);

            //Save to file
            doc.SaveToFile("job.docx", FileFormat.Docx);

        }    catch (Exception){}
    }
    public void f3()   // 32
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder F3 = new StringBuilder(TEMPprocitano);
            F3.Remove(0, 49);
            F3.Remove(32, 650);
            MessageBox.Show(F3.ToString());
            //Create a Word document

            Document doc = new Document();
            Section section = doc.AddSection();
            Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();

            //Append a Textbox to paragraph
            Spire.Doc.Fields.TextBox tb = paragraph.AppendTextBox(170, 20);

            //Set the position of Textbox
            tb.Format.HorizontalOrigin = HorizontalOrigin.Page;
            tb.Format.HorizontalPosition = 250;
            tb.Format.VerticalOrigin = VerticalOrigin.Page;
            tb.Format.VerticalPosition = 150;

            CharacterFormat format = new CharacterFormat(doc);
            format.FontName = "Calibri";
            format.FontSize = 11;
            format.Bold = false;



            Paragraph par1 = tb.Body.AddParagraph();
            par1.AppendText(F3.ToString()).ApplyCharacterFormat(format);

            //Save to file
            doc.SaveToFile("job.docx", FileFormat.Docx);


        }    catch (Exception) { }
```

Comment: Is ther  no  help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
string TEMPprocitano; 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    citanjeReda();
}
public void citanjeReda()
{
  if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
          {
     int brojRedova=File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName).Count();
     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
              for (int i = 0; i <= brojRedova; i++)
              {
                  TEMPprocitano = sr.ReadLine();
                  f1();  
              }
              sr.Close();
          }
}
public void f1()  //doc_pers_no 11
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder F1 = new StringBuilder(TEMPprocitano);
        F1.Remove(0, 22);
        F1.Remove(11, 698);
        MessageBox.Show(F1.ToString());

        //Create a Word document
        Document doc = new Document();
        Section section = doc.AddSection();
        Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();

        //Append a Textbox to paragraph
        Spire.Doc.Fields.TextBox tb = paragraph.AppendTextBox(170, 20);

        //Set the position of Textbox
        tb.Format.HorizontalOrigin = HorizontalOrigin.Page;
        tb.Format.HorizontalPosition = 150;
        tb.Format.VerticalOrigin = VerticalOrigin.Page;
        tb.Format.VerticalPosition = 50;
        tb.Format.NoLine = true;

        CharacterFormat format = new CharacterFormat(doc);
        format.FontName = "Calibri";
        format.FontSize = 11;
        format.Bold = false;



        Paragraph par1 = tb.Body.AddParagraph();
        par1.AppendText(F1.ToString()).ApplyCharacterFormat(format);

          ////// for F3
       StringBuilder F3 = new StringBuilder(TEMPprocitano);
            F3.Remove(0, 49);
            F3.Remove(32, 650);
            MessageBox.Show(F3.ToString());

            //Append a Textbox to paragraph
            Spire.Doc.Fields.TextBox tb3 = paragraph.AppendTextBox(170, 20);

            //Set the position of Textbox
            tb3.Format.HorizontalOrigin = HorizontalOrigin.Page;
            tb3.Format.HorizontalPosition = 70;
            tb3.Format.VerticalOrigin = VerticalOrigin.Page;
            tb3.Format.VerticalPosition = 70;
            tb3.Format.NoLine = true;

            Paragraph par3 = tb3.Body.AddParagraph();
            par3.AppendText(F3.ToString()).ApplyCharacterFormat(format);

        //Save to file
        doc.SaveToFile("job.docx", FileFormat.Docx);

    }    catch (Exception){}
}
```